What is the most efficient input for next zoom levels in tiling pyramid?
Lets say we have an input rasted image of some resolution/quality.
Also, we have some target resolution/quality we aim for for our tiles.
We start tiling process with

downsampling image for highest zoom level to meet target tiles resolution/quality
do the tiling for that zoom level

Now we go one zoom level down. In order to have tiles files sizes as small as possible, we need to do downsampling again to meet the same tile quality.
What should be the input for this step in order to achieve best performance of the process?
Should it be:

original image
whope downsampled image from previous step
4 tiles from previous zoom level combined together
something else?


You haven't mentioned how you intend to implement this but, rather than reinventing the wheel, have a look at gdal2tiles https://gdal.org/programs/gdal2tiles.html and create a folder for each intended zoom level. To maintain quality choose a format that supports lossless compression like GeoTIFF with either LZW or deflate compression and use a resampling method that gives you the quality you want, but the default 'average' should be considered first; 'quality' isn't a quantifiable metric so it's a process of trial and error.

@MichaelStimson you are right, sorry. One of the ideas is to paralelize gdal2tiles so that different processes do different set of zoom levels.
